# Insufficient Jest coverage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

I have the below code:

```
      <ReturnToLastSearch
        href={'/listings'}
        onClick={(e): void => {
          e.preventDefault();
          router.back();
        }}
      />
```

Inside `ReturnToLastSearch({ href, onClick }: Props)` has the following:

```
<a className="button" onClick={!onClick ? urlOnClick : onClick}>
```

Everything is working fine, except `jest` complains that my diff, which adds the `onClick` prop and the ternary has insufficient tests coverage!

I tried:

```
it('when onClick is defined uses onClick', () => {
  const call = ()=> ({back: jest.fn()});
  jest.mock('next/router', call)
  const { getByText } = render(<ReturnToLastSearch href="foo" onClick={call}/>);
  getByText(i18n.t('favorites.returnToLastSearch') as string).click();

  expect(router.back).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/listings')
});
```

I tried the above, which is the same as the version without `onClick` except for the expect and the mock of `router.back()`. However, I got an error telling me that the second argument in the `jest.mock()` should be an inline function.

What sort of test would make sense and also convince jest to leave me alone?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended-up with:

```
it('when onClick is defined uses onClick', () => {
  const call = jest.fn();
  const { getByText } = render(<ReturnToLastSearch href="foo" onClick={call} />);
  getByText(i18n.t('favorites.returnToLastSearch') as string).click();

  expect(call.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

It is not the most useful test, in my opinion. Yet, it did get `jest` off my back.